# Jenkins integration with JMeter - build is failed giving **Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar errorlevel=1**

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

[Jenkins Cosole output :updated 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udSGy.jpg)

When executing the Jmeter .JMX file using JMeter non GUI mode, it is working fine and I am able to get the .JTL file, but when I am trying to trigger the build using Jenkins it is getting failed giving **Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar
errorlevel=1** as message from console output .

Please note that I have added Perfomance Plugin in Jenkins and made jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml enabled in JMeter user properties. Please help if I am missing anything to setup the configuration.

[Build cmd command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGf9O.jpg)

C:\jmeter\bin\jmeter -J jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\jmeter\bin\edueka.jmx -l C:\jmeter\bin\report3.jtl

[code from CMD - JMeter non GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SpwM.jpg)
[JMeter Jar file access from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kEoq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your command, it should work normally.

Double check that the main JMeter executable .jar exists and the user which executes Jenkins process has correct permissions to access this file:

```
c:\jmeter\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar
```

The most common mistake is that users download source bundle of JMeter instead of the binary

[image]

Also the correct syntax for passing JMeter Properties via `-J` command line argument is:

- `J` needs to be capital
- remove the space between `J` and the property name

  ```
  C:\jmeter\bin\jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\jmeter\bin\edueka.jmx -l C:\jmeter\bin\report3.jtl
  ```

Also currently there is no need to switch [JMeter results format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) to XML, [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin/) is capable of processing JMeter results files in .CSV format as well

Comment: Yes. The jar file exists in bin folder and I can access the same from CMD using "java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar" and replaced with capital J and added extra space. Still the same error Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar""